# TabControl bind ItemsSource to List with an existing TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, tabcontrol

I have not been able to bind to my data such as `TabControl.ItemsSource = CourtCases` because it throws an exception:

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

...and using `TabControl.Items.Add(newTabItem)` might require more work since some tabs will have to be closed.

I have a `TabControl` where the first tab contains a `DataGrid` with a list of people and I want that whenever an item is clicked in the `DataGrid` a new tab is created containing the details for the person.

I want to pass the person object to the `TabItem` "scope/class" and should display the content of the person. I have created a `DataTemplate` for the person detail `TabItem` which you can see below;

```
<TabControl Name="AttorneysTabControl" Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="0">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AttorneyTabHeader">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attorney.Names}" Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AttorneyTabContent">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attorney.Names}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attorney.Age}"/>
                <ToolBar>
                    <Button ToolTip="">Delete</Button>
                    <Button ToolTip="">Edit</Button>
                </ToolBar>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Attorneys" Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <TabItem.Content>
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Height="Auto">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ...
            </Grid>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
    <!-- This part here -->
    <!-- I want this to repeat. I think I should use a UserControl for this since I want the content to have it's own class -->
    <TabItem ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AttorneyTabContent}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AttorneyTabHeader}" />
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Look into master-detail binding. Here's a [SAMPLE](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWPFMasterDetailBinding-c78566ae).

Comment: You're trying to use controls in a way they really aren't designed for. In cases like this, you should wrap the control in a UserControl, then expose your own ItemsSource DP, and handle managing the tabs manually in the codebehind.

Comment: Yes, Thats what I did. I realized it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

It's not impossible unless I'm missing something about your request. I will say that it doesn't sound like a good UX, but you know your users and your use case better than I would.

I put together something that I think will do what you want. You'd need to adapt it to your data. I hope it helps regardless. Please keep in mind this is very much only proof of concept code.

First is the XAML for the `MainWindow`. There's nothing special here. It starts off as a simple `TabControl` hosting a `TabItem` with a `Listbox`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTabControl1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTabControl1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TabControl Sample" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="Items" Type="{x:Type local:Item}">
            <local:Item Name="Item A" Value="1" />
            <local:Item Name="Item B" Value="2" />
            <local:Item Name="Item C" Value="3" />
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="ItemTabControl">
            <TabItem Header="Items">
                <ListBox x:Name="ItemListBox" ItemsSource="{StaticResource Items}"
                         SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind is where most of the interesting things happen. I do one of two things in the event handler based on whether the tab for the item already exists -- I create the tab or I select the tab.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();

    void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ItemListBox.SelectedItem is Item item) {
            // select the tab if one was already created for the item;
            // otherwise, create a new tab for it
            if (TabExists(item.Name, out TabItem tab)) {
                ItemTabControl.SelectedItem = tab;
            }
            else {
                var newItem = new ItemTabItem() {
                    Item = (Item)ItemListBox.SelectedItem
                };

                int newIndex = ItemTabControl.Items.Add(newItem);
                ItemTabControl.SelectedIndex = newIndex;
            }
        }
    }

    bool TabExists(string name, out TabItem tab)
    {
        tab = (from object item in ItemTabControl.Items
               let t = item as ItemTabItem
               where t != null && t.Item.Name == name
               select t).FirstOrDefault();

        return (tab != null);
    }
}
```

My `ItemTabItem` (I know awesome name right) takes care of displaying the `Item` class instance. Here's the XAML followed by the code behind.

```
<TabItem x:Class="WpfTabControl1.ItemTabItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTabControl1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Name" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Value" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

Now the code behind. We could just set the `DataContext` directly, but the property makes it more clear and allows me to set the header as well (probably could data bind it).

```
public partial class ItemTabItem : TabItem
{
    private Item item;

    public ItemTabItem() => InitializeComponent();

    public Item Item
    {
        get => item;
        set
        {
            item = value;
            DataContext = value;
            Header = item?.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Item` class is nothing special.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```